# Replacement memory allocators - pros and cons

Tags: c++, memory-efficiency

I am developing a hobby project to learn game engine development and to have a platform where I can test new ideas and have fun. Currently I have a quick-and-dirty multiplayer server and client using some third party libraries (enet for networking and Ogre3D for rendering). My "game" is mostly like a free-ride sandbox.

I have read some great articles about custom memory allocators and all the benefits - complete control, different strategies for different game objects, tracing and profiling. But also I have read that it is hard to develop an allocator which is better than the default one and that it might be hard to get it to play nicely with 3rd party libraries.

As it seems so hard to develop a custom allocator, I thought about using jemalloc but I'm not sure if it is a good choice for game server and/or client. 
I tried to find some 3rd party free/open source memory allocators designed specifically for game engines but I could not find anything production-ready.

I really would like to track allocated objects by their type - to see how many network packets I have, how much memory is taken by meshes, static objects, NPCS etc. and also to see where exactly are some memory leaks coming from. Also I would like to avoid having to restart my game server regularly because of memory fragmentation issues.

What is your experience? Is it a good idea to use some general purpose memory allocator (like jemalloc or tcmalloc) for game servers and clients or should I develop my own custom allocator (which seems a daunting task considering that I don't have enough experience with advanced C++)?

How do I integrate my custom memory allocator with popular 3rd party libraries (enet, Ogre3D, some physics libraries) if I have no idea what allocation mechanisms are used inside of those libraries?

If I decide not to use a custom allocator and stay with the one provided by MSVC runtime, is there any simple way to track my memory usage and prevent memory fragmentation without sacrificing performance?

Comment: Side note: you will always sacrifice performance, but if you're spamming enough allocations every "frame" of your runtime loop for the teensy overhead of tracking and reporting facilities... you're already in dangerous waters with your design.  And, before someone beats me to it, Premature Optimization Is The Root of All Evil.  Now onto real answers from everyone else =)